# Some function texts appear crossed by a line on netbeans ide

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I am using netbeans to develop simple android apps and i am looking at various short tutorials online.In one such tutorials that i have downloaded,some text is crossed by a line this .<del>`SmsManager`</del>

This is a small screenshot i made

[image]

What could be causing this?.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486092/what-does-strikethrough-mean-in-netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually indicates a deprecated class or method that you shouldn't use.

As for the specific deprecated class in your image :

> This class was deprecated in API level 4. Replaced by
>   android.telephony.SmsManager that supports both GSM and CDMA.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html))